# "hello world" on webcam capturing in HTML5 fails to work

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webcam

after a couple of hours of struggling here I am. I have the following code, which apparently should just start my webcam and prompt the stream on the webpage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5 Webcam Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="sourcevid" autoplay>Put your fallback message here.</video>
    <div id="errorMessage"></div>
    <script>
    video = document.getElementById('sourcevid');
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.getUserMedia; 
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    function gotStream(stream) {
       if (window.URL) {
          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
       } else {
          video.src = stream; // Opera.
       }

       video.onerror = function(e) {
          stream.stop();
       };

       stream.onended = noStream;
    }

    function noStream(e) {
       var msg = 'No camera available.';
       if (e.code == 1) {
          msg = 'User denied access to use camera.';
       }
       document.getElementById('errorMessage').textContent = msg;
    }


    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video: true}, gotStream, noStream);
    </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

No errors in the console, but no webcam stream either. Just the "User denied access to use camera.".

I tried another example, too long to show, but again apparently as soon as I try to run the page the stream falls into the `.onended` function:

```
function gotStream(stream) {
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.onerror = function () {
      stream.stop();
    };
    stream.onended = noStream;
    [...]
```

Where `noStream` is a simple function that prints something:

```
function noStream() {
   document.getElementById('errorMessage').textContent = 'No camera available.';
}
```

So basically when I'm running the second example I'm shown the "No camera available" on the webpage.

I'm running on Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94, I saw somewhere that I needed to enable some flags, but I couldn't find them in my `chrome://flags`; the flags' name were `Enable MediaStream` and `Enable PeerConnection`, but in my version I only have the second one, which I enabled.

Any thoughts? Is the API I'm using old by any means? Can somebody point me to some working example?

Thanks

Comment: may be not related but, check you haven't a webcam software running. Kind of software coming with the camera. I run into problems once...

Comment: Nice point, but no webcam software running. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.webrtc.org/running-the-demos the `getUserMedia` API is available on stable version as of Chrome 21 without the need to use any flag.

I think the error happens because you are trying to instantiate the stream without to define the url stream properly. Consider that you need to access the url stream differently in Chrome and Opera.

I would create the structure of your code as something like below:

```
function gotStream(stream) {
  if (window.URL) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream) || stream;
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.src = stream || stream; // Opera.
    video.play();
  }

  video.onerror = function(e) {
    stream.stop();
  };

  stream.onended = noStream;
}

function noStream(e) {
  var msg = 'No camera available.';
  if (e.code == 1) {
    msg = 'User denied access to use camera.';
  }
  document.getElementById('errorMessage').textContent = msg;
}

var options = {video: true, toString: function(){return 'video';}};

navigator.getUserMedia(options, gotStream, noStream);
```

**EDIT:**

You need to replace the source video element with the media stream. Edited the code above.

```
video = document.getElementById('sourcevid');
```

I recommend for reading these two articles:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/playing-with-html5-video-and-getusermedia-support/

Comment: Thanks. I tried your example but I get the `User denied access to use camera.` error. Moreover, apparently the `navigator` object doesn't have a function called `.getUserMedia()`, thus I'm using `.webkitGetUserMedia()`, could that be the error?

Comment: Try to add these two lines to: `navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.getUserMedia;
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;`

Comment: I added the lines on top of the script, but I get the same problem as before.

Comment: Did you make a reference to the `video` element? You need to obtain an instance to the `video` tag, then replace the content with the media stream obtained from the camera. I will post the updated code... Tell me if it's working.

Comment: Thanks for that. I put in my HTML something like this: `<video id="sourcevid" autoplay>Put your fallback message here.</video>` and added the line of code you added at the beginning of the javascript code, but still i get the same error message. Do you want me to update the code in my post with the full HTML+JS? Maybe there is some stupid mistake I can't figure at first sight...

Comment: I updated the code adding the missing HTML and modifying the rest with your script.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the problem could rely on the fact, that the `getUserMedia` is not fully standardized among browser. Webkit is expecting a string as the `getUserMedia` first parameter, Opera on the other end is expecting an object. See this article: http://creativejs.com/2012/03/getting-started-with-getusermedia/. Here is a common way using the same method among different browsers: https://github.com/rwldrn/navigator.getusermedia/blob/master/src/navigator.getusermedia.js. Another thing to consider: use `autoplay="autoplay"` in your markup, otherwise you'll see only the first frame.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17934/discussion-between-esimov-and-masiar)

Comment: You are correct- as of today, 5/12/2012 getUserMedia needs its respective vendor prefix:   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia